# Emacs Elnode can't show html pages

Tags: emacs

I have installed Emacs elnode by Marmalade, and everything looks OK. And I have read the manual carefully.

Now elnode has started, and I can view the folder public_html under .emacs.d\elnode folder.

If I input url `http://localhost:8000` in my Chrome, it will show following content:

---

/

.

..

default-webserver-image.png

test.html

---

But when I click the test.html file, chrome just can't get the response from elnode. I check my Emacs, the Message file provides two errors:

---

elnode-error: elnode--sentinel 'open from 127.0.0.1.' for process elnode-webserver-proc 127.0.0.1:2224 with buffer nil

elnode-error: Elnode status: elnode-webserver-proc 127.0.0.1:2224 open from 127.0.0.1

elnode-error: filter: calling handler on elnode-webserver-proc 127.0.0.1:2224

elnode-error: starting HTTP response on elnode-webserver-proc 127.0.0.1:2224

error in process filter: apply: Spawning child process: invalid argument

error in process filter: Spawning child process: invalid argument

---

I just don't know how to debug it. I also tried elnode-send-file function, it also doesn't work.

But If I run the Hello World example, it works:

```
(defun my-status-page (httpcon)
  (elnode-http-start httpcon 200 '("Content-type" . "text/html"))
  (elnode-http-return httpcon "<html><b>HELLO!</b></html>"))
(elnode-start 'my-status-page :port 8010)
```

The core problem is that Emacs can't send html page!

Is it necessary to do some basic configuration after installing elnode?

Thanks

Water Lin

Comment: what version of elnode is this? what version of emacs too?

Comment: Eamcs is 24.2, and elnode is the newest one which I get from https://github.com/nicferrier/elnode. And the Hello World example works fine. Elnode just can't send Html file.

Comment: how did you build it? I have just tested everything and it's fine. Try using elpakit to build it? that way you can't break dependancies.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that maybe you're on windows? maybe there's something going wrong there? can you confirm operating system?

Comment: Yes, my OS is Windows7. And I also tested it under Windows XP. Both system can't work. Thanks

Comment: Aha! ok. thanks... I'll check that because Windows should work but I don't regularly test releases on Windows. Look for an update release!

Comment: OK. Thanks, I am really interesting at this Mode in Emacs and thanks a lot for providing us this kind of tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest edition has solved the problem. If you meet the same problem as me, please download the newest edition.

My test environment is Windows7 & Emacs 24.2.1.